# My code is giving me the error IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple

Tags: python

I am trying to write some simple code and i get this error for some reason on python

```
hoursWorked = float(input('How many hours did worker {worker} work, on {day}'.format(worker = workers[counterW+1]), day = counterD)
```

It is giving me the error for counterD

```
Error: IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

Comment: Make a [mcve].  This doesn't produce the error described.  There isn't even a "replacement index 1" in this code.  This produces the error message, for example: `'{1}'.format(0)`.

Comment: You have closed the parentheses before the day parameter